# javascript regular expression to separate string at first equal sign

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a string I am trying to recognize in a text file. The text file has a specific field I need to extract in each line. Ex:

```
Field1 = This is the content for field 1
Field2 = This is the content for field 2
Field3 = This is the content for field 3, which is = to 4445
```

Assume I want to extract the content of field3 after its first "=" sign. How can I get that content "This is the content for field 3, which is = to 4445" including the second "=" sign but not the first one.
I am just getting into regular expressions, so I have not much experience. Here is what I tried:

```
=.*
```

but this will print the first "=" sign and everything after it. I want to omit the first = sign.

Likewise, what would be the regexp to get "Field3" without the first "=" sign? I know I could split the line based on the first equal sign but I really need to do it with regexps. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
.*?=\s*(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/JR7dR-CxUAkM0GxI)

- `.` means all characters except newlines
- `+` means one more of that character
- `()` denotes a capture group
- `*` means zero or more
- `\s` means white space
- `*?` Zero or more a's (lazy)

Extract it out of the capture group. It should be in your first capture group. Remember the entire array is stored in the `0` indexed of match.

```
var match = myRegexp.exec(input);
alert(match[1]);
```

please read more about [regex here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and use [debugexx.com](http://www.debuggex.com/) to experiment.

Comment: Your solution prints everything after the second = sign. If I give it Field3 = this is field3 = 3,    it will only print 3

Comment: Does the debugx do a graphic line wrap on very large expressions or is it one gigantic wide png file? Or, can it be turned vertically and formatted?

Comment: @sln No, you cannot change how the graphic representation will come out.

Comment: That also works, what about the Field3 section? How would you extract that? I tried Field3 (?==), but this would only work if Field3 has spaces between the "=" sign. If I do Field3=This is field3 = 3. It would not work.

Comment: @JuanCarlos it seems like it works... [Debuggex Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/13wSAdl5al6vB0D3)

Comment: You shouldn't need the `.*?`=\s*(.*) in this regex.

Comment: @sln let me answer your first question about debuggex. It's dynamically shown to you with java script then you click essentially a convert to image function and it converts that javascript into an image (not sure how) but that's how it essentially works. Also, agreed my original answer didn't actually have the `.*?` but it doesn't make full "matches" if you don't include it. So, essentially i did it for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a capture group. Something which will be a bit like that:

```
str.match(/=\s*(.*)$/)[1];
```

Or you do:

```
res = str.match(/=\s*(.*)$/);
console.log(res[1]);
```

If you want a 'safer' regex, you might try this:

```
str.match(/^[^=]+=\s*(.*)$/);
```

`^` matches the beginning of line;

`[^=]+` matches any characters except the equal sign;

`=` will then match the first equal sign;

`(.*)$` will capture everything after the first equal sign until the end of the string.

Comment: I tried this in a online regular expression tested and it does nto work. Any ideas why? here is the website I am using http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: @JuanCarlos It's okay :)

Comment: How would you get the Field3 part?

Comment: @JuanCarlos See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dr6LM/) for an example code with the above regex.

Answer (score 0):

To match `Field3` only you may use lookahead assertion:

```
str.match(/Field3(?=\s*=)/);
```

This shall match `Field3` if it's followed by the equal sign, but won't include the equal sign in the match string.

Comment: How could you make it work with either Field3 = This is field 3=3.   and Field3=This is field 3=3. Sometimes the text file I have will not have spaces between the = sign. Any ideas?